# Notation of inverse matrix and confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, matrix-calculus

I would like to know if when we read that $A$ is a square matrix and $A^{-1}$ appears at some points without being explicitly defined, is there a "mutual agreement" to know that $A^{-1}$ is the inverse matrix of $A$ that is the one satisfying $AA^{-1}$=$A^{-1}A=I$ ? And is this applies also to the notation $A^{-1/2}$ to say that  $A^{-1/2}$ is the inverse matrix of $A^{1/2}$ where $A^{1/2}$ satisfies $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}=A$ and $A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}=A^{-1}$ or there is condition in order to use this kind of notation ?

I mean, this notation makes directly sense in $\mathbb{R}$ for exemple but for matrices I find it tricky.

Thank you

Comment: In a group $G$, for example in $G=GL_n(K)$, the elements $g$ have an inverse, denoted by $g^{-1}$. So this is standard and not really "tricky". For $n=1$ and $K=\Bbb R$ it is the group $(\Bbb R^{\times},\cdot)$, where you said it makes directly sense. But it also does for $GL_n(K)$ in general. So as soon as $g=A^{1/2}$ exists in $GL_n(K)$, the notation $A^{-1/2}=g^{-1}$ makes sense.

Comment: I did not try to see this with the point of view provided by  group, I will definitively look at this keeping in mind what you wrote. Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, $A^{-1}$ is usually the inverse matrix (when $A$ is an invertible square matrix, otherwise it isn't defined).

For $A^{-1/2}$, I would guess it means $(A^{1/2})^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{1/2}$, but... the square root of the matrix is not always defined (for matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb R$). For example, even a simple example like

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)$$

has infinitely many "square roots" in the sense you mean, for example

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} -1&0\\ 0&1\end{array}\right)^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&-1\end{array}\right)^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0.8&0.6\\ 0.6&-0.8\end{array}\right)^2$$

Usually, the good definition is given by the following theorem:

**Theorem** Let $A$ be a positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrix (with coefficients in $\mathbb R$). There exists a *unique* positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

So if $A$ is positive semidefinite, you can define $A^{1/2}$ as the unique $B$ as before, that is still positive semidefinite.

Comment: Indeed I was meaning the inverse square root as the unique matrix satisfying the relation you wrote. I did not have in mind this simple example, thank you a lot !